# Call a function within a globally defined function?

Tags: jquery

Ive created a function to pause a youtube video. When I call the function just after its defined it works fine.

However how can I call this pause function from within other functions? As onYouTubeIframeAPIReady is set in window does this make it a global function? So this should make it possible to call my pause function through it?

```
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
            $youtubeVideos.each(function () {
              var player = new window.YT.Player(this.id, {
                events: {
                  onReady: function (e) {
                    var state = e.target.getPlayerState();
                    if (state === window.YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING || state === window.YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                      $element.addClass('video-playing');
                      activePlayer = player;
                    }
                  },
                  onStateChange: function (e) {
                    if (e.data === window.YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING || e.data === window.YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                      $element.addClass('video-playing');
                      activePlayer = player;
                    } else {
                      $element.removeClass('video-playing');
                      activePlayer = null;
                    }
                  }
                }
              });

              // Video pause function
              function pauseTheVid() {
                player.pauseVideo();
              }

              // This works 
              $('#trigger').click(function () {
                pauseTheVid();
              });

            });
          };


      // Some other function that is nested somewhere else in my file. 
      // This doesnt work: 
      $('#trigger2').click(function () {
        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady().pauseTheVid();
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Video pause function
this.pauseTheVid = function() {
    player.pauseVideo();
}
```

When changing it to an object property you should be able to create an instance of `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` and call the function. To ereference it from other functions within the same object you would use a reference to the same scope.

```
var self = this;
// This works 
$('#trigger').click(function () {
    self.pauseTheVid();
});
```

creating an instance could be done using `new`.

```
window.youtube = function(){
   var self = this;
   this.play = function(){
        console.log('play');
   }
   this.anotherFunction = function(){
        self.play();
   }
}
//use this syntax in whatever file or scope you are
var yt = new youtube();
yt.play();
yt.anotherFunction();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b796zhv5/1/)

Or in your special case:

```
  $('#trigger2').click(function () {
    var yt = new onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
    //pauseTheVid is an object property as told before.
    yt.pauseTheVid();
  });
```

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood me. The #trigger click function is already working. What I need to do is call the pause function from within totally different places within my file(s), which might be nested within completely different functions.

Comment: Yeah. see the last updated example. When in a totally different file, you simply create the object there and call the function you need. The example also involves calling it from the same object scope.

Comment: IM looking into this but FYI that JSFiddle link doesnt do anything.

Comment: it gives console logs. 2 times. well i tried my best explaining it. You won't be able to do this without any prototyping.